# How to create this custom node and arrow in TikZ for network diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, nodes, tikz-node

I am creating an activity-on-arrow project diagram for my Critical Path method lecture. I could able to create the customized node for the same as indicated in black color in the attached image. However, I would like to build upon the existing code, to incorporate the additional components as indicated in red in the attached diagram. I am not able to get. The red indicates the expected result, the color need not be red for the answer. Kindly help me.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{sectors/.style n args={5}{%
circle,
draw,
minimum width=#4,
append after command={%
\pgfextra{ %
 \draw (\tikzlastnode.center) -- (\tikzlastnode.south);
\draw (\tikzlastnode.west)   -- (\tikzlastnode.east);
\path (\tikzlastnode.center) -- node[#5] {#1} (\tikzlastnode.north);  
\path (\tikzlastnode.center) -- node[#5] {#2} (\tikzlastnode.south west); 
\path (\tikzlastnode.center) -- node[#5] {#3} (\tikzlastnode.south east);}}}}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=7cm,ultra thick]
\node [circle split,
     draw,
     minimum width=2cm,
     append after command={%
     \pgfextra{\draw (\tikzlastnode.center) -- (\tikzlastnode.south) ;
              } 
              }]  (a)  {};
\node[yshift=1.5em] at (a.center) {\LARGE \textbf{1}};  
\node[xshift=-1.2em,yshift=-1.2em] at (a.center) {\LARGE $a$}; 
\node[xshift= 1.2em,yshift=-1.2em] at (a.center) {\LARGE $b$};  
\node [circle split,
     draw,
     minimum width=2cm,
     append after command={%
     \pgfextra{\draw (\tikzlastnode.center) -- (\tikzlastnode.south) ;
              } 
              }]  (b) [right of=a] {};
\node[yshift=1.5em] at (b.center) {\LARGE \textbf{2}};  
\node[xshift=-1.2em,yshift=-1.2em] at (b.center) {\LARGE $c$}; 
\node[xshift= 1.2em,yshift=-1.2em] at (b.center) {\LARGE $d$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (a) -- (b);  
\path[]
(a) edge [above] node {\LARGE a \qquad \textbf{A}\qquad b} (b)
(a) edge [below] node {\LARGE b \quad $\mathrm{D}_{1-2}$ \quad a} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proposal. It uses `fit` and `label`s and so on. The perhaps most important point is that

```
\pgfextra{\draw (\tikzlastnode.center) -- (\tikzlastnode.south) ;
          }
```

got replaced by

```
 append after command={%
 (\tikzlastnode.center) edge (\tikzlastnode.south) 
          },
```

Why? The pgf manual v3.1.5 says on p. 170 about `\pgfextra`

> Note that this operation should only be used by real experts and
>   should only be used deep inside clever macros, not on normal paths.

and I have seen this going terribly wrong. (I understand that this is not your fault. The `\pgfextra` practice can be found in several posts, most of the authors stopped using it except for a few. So this remark is not addressed to the OP asking the question but to those who keep propagating the bad `\pgfextra` practice despite warnings they have received.)

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,positioning,shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick,font=\LARGE]
\node [circle split,
     draw,
     minimum width=2cm,
     append after command={%
     (\tikzlastnode.center) edge (\tikzlastnode.south) 
              },
     label={[alias=a-ne]above right:{$b$}},
     label={[alias=a-nw]above left:{$a$}},
     label={[alias=a-sw]below left:{$a$}},
     label={[alias=a-se]below right:{$b$}},
     ]  (a)  {$\boldsymbol{1}$\nodepart{lower}$a\quad b$};
\path node[fit=(a-ne)(a-sw)(a-ne)(a-se),draw=none](F0){}
  let \p1=($(F0.north east)-(a.center)$),
    \p2=($(a.center)-(F0.south west)$),
    \n1={max(\x1,\x2,\y1,\y2)} in
  node[fit={([xshift=-\n1,yshift=-\n1]a.center)([xshift=\n1,yshift=\n1]a.center)},
    inner sep=0pt,draw] (F){}
  foreach \X in {west,south,east,north} {(a.\X) edge (F.\X)};    
\node [circle split,
     draw,
     minimum width=2cm,
     append after command={%
      (\tikzlastnode.center) edge (\tikzlastnode.south) 
              }]  (b) [right=6cm of a] {$\boldsymbol{2}$\nodepart{lower}$c\quad d$};
\draw[-latex,ultra thick,nodes={text height=1.2em,text depth=0.4ex}] (a) -- 
 node[pos=0.25,above=0.5ex,draw]{$a$}
 node[pos=0.25,below=0.5ex,draw]{$b$}
 node[pos=0.5,above=0.5ex]{$\boldsymbol{A}$}
 node[pos=0.5,below=0.5ex]{$D_{1-2}$}
 node[pos=0.75,above=0.5ex,draw]{$b$}
 node[pos=0.75,below=0.5ex,draw]{$a$}
(b);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Schrödinger's cat this works perfectly fine. Is it possible to divide the square node also into compartments (four parts) as in my attachments, i.e. line or border separating the compartments, that looks good? Thank you very much.

Comment: @RameshKannan Sure. Sorry, I just missed it.

Comment: Schrödinger's cat. Thank you very much for your continued support. You are my hero...!